# Node.js module: export async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-modules

In the [given example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697061/how-to-manage-multiple-js-files-server-side-with-node-js/#answer-5697088) it is demonstrated, how to export a variable, or a function from a custom module. How could one export an asynchronous function in a similar manner and then call it from app.js something like:

```
// app.js

var things = require("./someThings");

await things.getSomeThingsAsync();
```

**EDIT:**

The example (answer on Stackoverflow) pointed to by the above link contains the following code:

```
// someThings.js

(function() {
    var someThings = ...;

    ...

    module.exports.getSomeThings = function() {
        return someThings();
    }

}());

// main.js

var things = require("someThings");
...
doSomething(things.getSomeThings());
```

Say inside of the module's incapsulated function a asynchronous function exists, which you would like to expose to whoever imports the module. For example:

```
(function() {
    ...
    const doSomethingAsync = (time) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve(42), time)
        })
    }

    //const doSomething = async () => {
    async function doSomething () {
        let answer1 = await doSomethingAsync(3000)
        let answer2 = await doSomethingAsync(1000)
        return answer1 + answer2
    }
    ...
    /*module.exports.doSomething = function() {
        return doSomething();
    }*/
    module.exports.doSomething = async function() {
        return doSomething();
    }
}());
```

How would you expose the `doSomething` function in similar fashion as the in the original answer it is done for `someThings` - how can the referred to answer be changed in such a way, that when exporting functions, it lets you use the `await` keyword? It will then be used as:

```
// app.js

var things = require("./someThings");

console.log(await things.doSomething());
```

I have tried multiple approaches, but I always get:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the error. It says

> SyntaxError: await is only valid **in** async function

not "**for** async function"

There is no problem with your export. It is simply not possible to use `await` outside of a function marked `async`. Therefore the bug is in `app.js`. It should be:

```
var things = require("./someThings");

async function app () {
    console.log(await things.doSomething());
}

app().then(() => console.log('done calling app()'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this :

```
//yourModule.js

let yourModule={};
yourModule.you=async()=>{
    //something await...
}
modules.export = yourModule;


//app.js

let yourModule = require('<pathToModule>');

async function test()
{
    await yourModule.you();  //your `await` here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715484/correct-async-function-export-in-node-js) of this question.

You can simply **assign** the function (or a function expression) to a **property** (or just the entirety) of `**module.exports’**.

For example:

```
async function AsyncStuff () { ... }

module.exports.myAsyncThing = myAsyncStuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var things = require("./someThings");
let result = getResult();
async function getResult() {
    return await things.getSomeThingsAsync();
}
```